# Simple C++ if else

Tags: c++

I'm trying to insert a newline into a file, if  a user supplied int is not already on file, if it is, then newline should not be added.

The code below doesn't add new entry if `acc == accNum` is true, but in the else block(for adding new entry), same multiple entries are added. I initially moved the else out of the `while`, but still doesn't solve the problem

```
while (fin >> acc >> first_name >> last_name >> bal){
    if (acc == accNum){
        cout << "Account already exist, please check." << endl;
        fin.close();
    } else {

        ofstream fout("bank.txt", ios::app);

        fout << accNum << " " << fname << " " << lname << " " << accBal << endl;
        cout << "New Account Inserted." << endl;

        fout.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need to call `close` on an [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) the destructor will do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code does exactly what you made it do. Lets read it out loud:

> While the input is correctly separated into values, do:
>
> - If `acc` is equal to `accNum`, print "Account already exist, please check.",
> - If not - add the account

Perhaps what you wanted instead is:

> 1. While the input is correctly separated into values, do:
>
>    - Store all `acc` in a collection.
> 2. Check whether `accNum` was found in the collection

If that's the case, you should certainly use one of the classes C++ supplies you. In your current case, probably a `std::set` would be the best solution, since it gives you the ability to [add](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/insert/) elements in linear, amortized time and [search](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/count/) for them in logarythmic time.

So your code should look more like this:

```
std::set<int> accounts;  // Or any other type instead of int. I'm guessing a bit here
while (fin >> acc >> first_name >> last_name >> bal)
   accounts.insert(acc);
if(accounts.count(accNum)
   cout << "Account already exist, please check." << endl;
else{
   // add the acc to the file
}
```

You could also define a class to store the total account data, which would probably look something like this:

```
struct account{
   int acc;
   std::string first_name;
   std::string last_name;
   someType bal;
}
```

And store them in a `std::vector`. If you wanted to store the records in a `std::set`, you would need to overload the `operator<` for it, or provide your own comparator function in the [constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/).

However it may seem like needles effort, it should make the program much more readable when you finish it. Also - you'll get some practice in object oriented programming, which is what C++ is for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the while loop to read through the data and set a flag if it finds what you're looking for. After the while loop, check the status of the flag and if it is not set, do the else code that you have.

The way it is written now, after each line that doesn't match, it will output the new account. With the change I suggested, we first go through the entire file and look for the account. If not found, then we insert.